# Coordinate descent with equality and inequality constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have an intuitive understanding of why the simple method of coordinate descent does not work with linearly coupled constraints such as;

$$\min_x\sum_if_i(x_i)$$
$$s.t.$$
$$Ax=b$$

If we try to minimize the above problem with respect to one variable at a time, it doesn't converge to the optimal solution, even though $f$ is convex. How can we more formally explain the reason?

Also, are there any iterative methods to solve the above problem, with additional inequality constraints such as:

$$\min_x\sum_if_i(x_i)$$
$$s.t.$$
$$Ax=b$$
$$Gx\le H$$

I have read about block coordinate descent methods proposed for linearly coupled constraints, but I have a more complex model in hand with the inequality constraints. Thank you.

Comment: Look at $\min \{ x_1^2+x_2^2 | x_1+x_2 = 1  \}$. If you require iterates to be feasible, then you cannot 'move' using coordinate wise descent. A projected gradient approach would work nicely here.

Comment: @copper.hat thank you, do you think an augmented lagrangian approach is worth giving a shot? (get rid of the constraints and apply coordinate descent to the lagrangian function?)

Comment: Well, you could, but why not try a projected gradient approach? Why are you constrained to a coordinate descent approach?